# How to show mysql data in html input text?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created html file with generated text, and i want to populate fields like name and date from mysql database. The thing is i am trying to show data from mysql in html input text tag. But it only shows letter S. 
This is my php code:

```
    <?php



    $db_host = ''; // Server Name
    $db_user = ''; // Username
    $db_pass = ''; // Password
    $db_name = ''; // Database Name

    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = "SELECT ime_prezime,datumpocetka,datumzavrsetka,broj_dana,sektor,
mesto,tip,obrazlozenje,vreme_slanja
FROM godisnji
WHERE id=74";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And this is a part of my html code:

```
<p style="text-align:justify">1. Zaposlenom <input  name="lname" type="text" value="<?php  echo $result['ime_prezime'];?>"/>
na poslovima $posao, se odobrava
korišćenje godišnjeg odmora za 2018. godinu, u trajanju od 20 radnih dana.</p>
```

Comment: Seems you are not executing your query... the google search term should be "mysqli execute query"

Comment: Check this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: You open a Database Connection. You then define a query as a String, then you close the Database Connection... The bits where you run the query and get the results back etc are missing.  I Suggest that you read up on mysqli.

Comment: try this:
    $result = "SELECT ime_prezime,datumpocetka,datumzavrsetka,broj_dana,sektor,
mesto,tip,obrazlozenje,vreme_slanja
FROM godisnji
WHERE id=74";

 mysqli_query($con,$result );

mysqli_close($con);

Comment: @B001 Is it something like this code: $retval = mysqli_query($con,$result );

Comment: _Is it something like this code..._ Yea!!!

Comment: @B001  i tried with this code: mysqli_query($con,$result ) but it stills shows only letter S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because...

Now this is very basic and you should learn to use PDO or at least the mysqli class. But for now...

This is a little demonstration code... ( It may have bugs as I have not run it )

```
<?php
// The Database Connection Stuff should be in it's own file
// and included in each file that requires a database connection.
$db_host = ''; // Server Name
$db_user = ''; // Username
$db_pass = ''; // Password
$db_name = ''; // Database Name
$con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


// Create the SQL
$sql = "SELECT ime_prezime,datumpocetka,datumzavrsetka,broj_dana,sektor,
mesto,tip,obrazlozenje,vreme_slanja
FROM godisnji
WHERE id=74";

// Run the SQL statement
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
// Read back the ROW as an associative array
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

// DEBUG to learn what you get  back and CHECK it's what you expect!
var_dump($result);
// If it exists...
echo ($result['ime_prezime']);

mysqli_close($con);

// Then Read up on how to use PDO or mysqli Class
```

And as a suggestion, due to the fact you won't always have a valid value you could use instead of...

```
<?php  echo $result['ime_prezime'];?>
```

Try this

```
<?= isset($result['ime_prezime'])?$result['ime_prezime']:'';?>
```

The above tests whether $result['ime_prezime'] exists, and if it does it will print it, else it will print ''.

Look up "Ternary Operators in PHP"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$db_host = ''; // Server Name
$db_user = ''; // Username
$db_pass = ''; // Password
$db_name = ''; // Database Name

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user , $db_pass , $db_name );


if ($conn->connect_error)
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $conn->connect_error;
}

$result = "SELECT ime_prezime,datumpocetka,datumzavrsetka,broj_dana,sektor,
           mesto,tip,obrazlozenje,vreme_slanja FROM godisnji WHERE id=74";

$sqlQuery = $conn->query($result);

$value = $sqlQuery->fetch_assoc()['ime_prezime'];



echo "<p style='text-align:justify'>1. Zaposlenom <input 
        name='lname'type='text' value='".$value."'/></p>";

$conn->close();

?>
```